# Keyboard only usage of new Find/Replace Dialog in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij 2016 and earlier it has been possible to perform all navigations from the Find/Replace dialogs using just the keyboard.

Intellij 2017.X has restructured the Find/Replace dialog. While most operations are still achievable via the keyboard it is not clear how to invoke the "Open in Find Window" . There is no apparent accelerator available.

[image]

Here is the entire `Find in Path` dialog for context:

[image]

I use Find/Replace dozens of times a day and so having it be keyboard only is of some importance: hoping someone may have discovered a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a shortcut, its even displayed in your screenshot

[image: ecreenshot]

It's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> on Linux and <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on Mac OS

Here it is on your screenshot[image]

Comment: That text does not show for me - as shown in *my* screenshot. However the shortcut *does* work!  thx!

Comment: @javadba I updated my answer, the shortcut is also displayed in your screenshot ;)

Comment: I have been presented that dialog maybe fifty times but did not notice that. It is relevant that I have 4.5 diopters correction but do not wear glasses when working on computer.